# Holomorphic extensions of harmonic functions in $\mathbb R^n$, $n\geq2$

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, complex-geometry, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $\Omega$ be a (smooth) domain in $\mathbb R^n$, $n\geq2$ and $u$ be a harmonic function in $\Omega$ continuous up to the boundary.

I read somewhere (but unfortunately I don't remember where) that if $B_{\mathbb R^n}(p,r)$ is a ball contained in $\Omega$, then there exists a function $\tilde u$ in $B_{\mathbb C^n}(p, r/\sqrt{2})$ which is holomorphic with respect to each variable and coincides with $u$ in $B_{\mathbb R^n}(p,r/\sqrt{2})$. That is, $\tilde u$ is a function of $z_1, ..., z_n$ such that $\frac {\partial}{\partial \bar z_i} \tilde u = 0$, $1 \leq i \leq n$.

I have two ideas on how to show this (hopefully):

1. use that $u(x) = \int_{\partial B(p,r)} u(\xi) P(x,\xi)\,d\xi$ where $P$ is the Poisson kernel, and somehow change the Poisson kernel for an "adequate complex extension".
2. use that $u(x) = \sum_{\alpha} a_\alpha P_\alpha(x-p)$ where $P_\alpha$ is a harmonic homogeneous polynomial of degree $\alpha$ (Taylor expansion of $u$ around $p$). Then, somehow "complexify" each harm. homog. pol. to obtain a power series.

Do you know of any reference on how to complete these arguments? Or, ideally, a good reference where I can read about complexification of harmonic functions and applications? Also, I am interested in reference texts on holomorphic functions in multiple variables since I know very little about the topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Textbooks on holomorphic functions of several complex variables**
I will first answer your request for a reference text on holomorphic functions of several complex variables, since it is simpler to answer. In my opinion the best textbook to start a journey in this realm is the textbook by Krantz [1a] since it tries to give a flavor of all approaches involved i.e. the PDE based approach named after Cauchy and Riemann, the integral representation approach named after Cauchy and (to a lesser extent) the algebraic approach named after Oka and Cartan. In this sense it is a truly introductive text, despite being fully rigorous. As a second reading, I'd advise to have a look at the classical textbook of Range [2a], focused on the integral representation approach: this is however a suggestion biased by my analytic tastes and by the fact that this approach has been flourished in the last 50 years and it seems to go further on.

**Holomorphic extension of harmonic functions**
It seems to me that you are mixing two different, nevertheless deeply related, statements. The results are precisely the following ones:
**Theorem 1** ([1b], §5 Lemma pp. XXV.22-XXV.26). Let $u$ be an harmonic function on the ball $B_{\Bbb R^n}(r)$ centered in $0\in\Bbb R^n$: then $u$ can be continued as an holomorphic function of several variables on the Lie ball
$$
\mathscr{B}_{\Bbb C^n}(r) =\Big\{z\in\Bbb C^n : |z|^2+2\sqrt{|x|^2|y|^2-\langle x,y\rangle^2}< R^2\Big\}
$$
Aronszajn proves this theorem (originally due to Pierre Lelong, as stated in [5b] p.87) by using the Poisson formula, as does Hayman with the following result.
**Theorem 2** ([4b], theorem 1, pp. 155-158). Let $u$ be an harmonic function on the ball $B_{\Bbb R^n}(r)$ centered in $0\in\Bbb R^n$: then the power series expansion of $u$ converges on the interior of the ball $B_{\Bbb R^n}(r/\sqrt{2})$ but in general not on its boundary nor its exterior.

Obviously, the fact that the balls are centered in $0\in\Bbb R^n$ ($0\in\Bbb C^n$) is not a restriction in generality: the result holds for any ball centered around a generic point $p\in\Bbb R^n$ ($p\in\Bbb C^n$) as it can be seen by applying a simple linear change of variable (i.e. the composition of a rotation and a translation) to the base vector space $\Bbb R^n$ ($\Bbb C^n$).

Theorem 1 was further generalized and extended to polyharmonic functions in references [2b] and [3b] by using Almansi's expansion: theorem 2 was later "sharpened" by Khavin in [5b] (where there's also a brief but complete historical note on these researches). I think the best sources on these matters are perhaps the ones I listed below but beware, they are not an easy read.

### References

**Textbooks on holomorphic functions of several complex variables**

[1a] Steven G. Krantz, *Function theory of several complex variables.* Reprint of the 1992 2nd ed. with corrections. (English) Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS), AMS Chelsea Publishing (ISBN 0-8218-2724-3/hbk), pp. xvi+564 (2001), [MR1846625](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1846625), [Zbl 1087.32001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1087.32001).

[2a] R. Michael Range, *Holomorphic functions and integral representations in several complex variables* (English), Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 108, Berlin-Heidelberg-New York: Springer-Verlag. pp. XIX+386 (1986), [MR0847923](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0847923), [Zbl 0591.32002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0591.32002).

**Holomorphic extension of harmonic functions**

[1b] Nachman Aronszajn, *[General Cauchy formulas in $\Bbb C^n$](http://www.numdam.org/item/SEDP_1975-1976____A26_0/)*, Séminaire Équations aux dérivées partielles (Polytechnique) dit aussi "Séminaire Goulaouic-Schwartz" (1975-1976), Exposé no. 25, pp. 28, [MR481075](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=481075), [Zbl 0337.32002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0337.32002).

[2b] Nachman Aronszajn, Thomas M. Creese, Leonard J. Lipkin, *Polyharmonic functions* (English), Oxford Mathematical Monographs, Oxford: Oxford University Press (Clarendon Press), pp. X+265 (1983), ISBN: 0-19-853906-1, [MR0745128](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0745128), [Zbl 0514.31001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0514.31001).

[3b] Vazgain Avanissian, "Sur les fonctions harmoniques d’ordre quelconque et leur prolongement analytique dans $\Bbb C^N$", (French)
Séminaire P. Lelong - H. Skoda, Analyse, Années 1980/81, et: Les fonctions plurisousharmoniques en dimension finie ou infinie, Colloq. Wimereux 1981, Lecture Notes in Mathematics 919, pp. 192-281 (1982), [MR0658887](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0658887), [Zbl 0534.31004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0534.31004).

[4b] Walter Kurt Hayman, "[Power series expansions for harmonic functions](https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/2.2.152)" (English), Bulletin of the London Mathematical Society 2, 152-158 (1970),  [MR0267114](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0267114), [Zbl 0201.43302](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0201.43302).

[5b] Viktor Petrovich Khavin, "[A remark on Taylor series of harmonic functions](https://doi.org/10.1090/trans2/146/11)" (English. Russian original) Translations Series 2, American Mathematical Society 146, pp. 85-90 (1990); translation from Multidimensional complex analysis, Work Collection, Krasnoyarsk 1985, 192-197 (1985), [MR0899349](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0899349), [Zbl 0714.31001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0714.31001).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found Hayman's paper but I'm very interested in Khavin's paper now.

Comment: @HHN the paper of Khavin is available on the website of the American Mathematical Society, but is "restricted access". If you have problems in getting a copy of it, contact me with my private e-mail.